# Why does AVAudioPlayer keep playing when headphones are unplugged?

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, avaudioplayer

Apple indicates that when headphones are unplugged, iOS automatically stops playing.

While this is true when using **AVPlayer**, it actually does NOT work as expected when using **AVAudioPlayer**, instead audio keeps continuing to play from the built in speakers.

Link to Apple's site: 
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/HandlingAudioHardwareRouteChanges/HandlingAudioHardwareRouteChanges.html

Answer (score 3):

You need to observe the hardware rout change observer and based on callback, You can just stop playing.

Setup your player - play audio (even on silent mode) and silence other music:

```
let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
_ = try? audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, with: .duckOthers)
_ = try? audioSession.setActive(true)
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(audioRouteChanged), name: .AVAudioSessionRouteChange, object: nil)


func audioRouteChanged(note: Notification) {
   if let userInfo = note.userInfo {
       if let reason = userInfo[AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReasonKey] as? Int  {
       if reason == AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReason.oldDeviceUnavailable.hashValue {
       // headphones plugged out
       player.stop()
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Important: Media playback apps should pause playback if the route change reason is AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReasonOldDeviceUnavailable, but should not if the reason is AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReasonOverride.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure but Try this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSError *setCategoryErr;
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:&setCategoryErr];

    // Detects when the audio route changes (ex: headphones unplugged)
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(audioHardwareRouteChanged:) name:AVAudioSessionRouteChangeNotification object:nil];
    // Don't forget to remove notification in dealloc method!!
}

- (void)audioHardwareRouteChanged:(NSNotification *)notification {
    NSInteger routeChangeReason = [notification.userInfo[AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReasonKey] integerValue];
    if (routeChangeReason == AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReasonOldDeviceUnavailable) {
        // if we're here, The old device is unavailable == headphones have been unplugged, so stop manually!
        [self.player stop];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [document you linked to](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/HandlingAudioHardwareRouteChanges/HandlingAudioHardwareRouteChanges.html)

> **Important**: Media playback apps *should* pause playback if the route change reason is `AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReasonOldDeviceUnavailable`, but should not if the reason is `AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReasonOverride`.

"Should" can indicate either duty or the likelihood of an event. 
In this case it means it is *your* duty to implement pausing when headphones, etc, are unplugged and **not** that it is likely to happen without any intervention on your part (as you've seen, it doesn't).

Looking at it with fresh eyes, the documentation *is* ambiguous. Should was not a good word choice.

Comment: That's a good point, I have read quoted sentence once more and it's misleading indeed. While I think it does answer my question, it still does not explain why AVPlayer does stop automatically and AVAudioPlayer does not. I guess Apple was just inconsistent.

Comment: Ha ha, maybe the should does refer to probability! In any case AVPlayer is documented to pause on device unavailable and AVAudioPlayer is not: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiosession/responding_to_audio_session_route_changes you could log a bug against AVAudioPlayer, but it’s a very old and abandoned feeling class. I think people only use it for its level monitoring. Or you could observe the notification and pause your AVAudioPlayer as necessary.